# New sharepoint group default owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, access, access-rights, sharepoint-site

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to set a certain security group as a default owner for any new created sharepoint groups.

We currently have a following setup:
AD environment with 2 security groups
Employees - Users
Sharepoint_owners - Owners

We have synced our AD to AzureAD and this way we can utilize these security groups in sharepoint.

Whenever a User creates a new sharepoint site that same user will be that site's one and only owner by default unless he/she adds other owners/users during site creation. During creation only other PEOPLE can be added as owners or members so we can't cut corners by trying to add the Sharepoint_owners during creation. So far we have first created the site and then from advanced permission settings we have added these 2 security groups into members and owner gorups, each to their own one.

The actual question here is:

Is it possible to have Sharepoint_owners as a default owner for ANY created groups and sites on top of the the person whoever happens to create the site?

Answer (score 0):

If people are just creating sites in the browser, then no, there's no way to do this.

The standard way to achieve this is by automating the site provisioning process via code. This is sort of a broad topic and you have a lot of options. If you're interested this would be a good topic for a follow up question here.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous SharePoint on-premise environment (for example, SharePoint2010
), we can use "Set up group" option within a site to create and assign the default Owner group.

But so far, there's no way we can do the same thing.

You should manually create group: Site Permissions > Create Group